# Randomly parsing files in Python from the command line

Tags: python, parsing, command, arguments

When I was programming in C I had figured out a way in order to parse command line arguments for my program in any order, but I just would have to specify what the file was.
So my input was something like this: `./exe.out -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -a <someotherfile> etc...` And this could get mixed up like so: `./exe.out -o <outputfile> -i <inputfile> -a <someotherfile> etc...`

Now I need to do this in python. Meaning, having a method which will handle command line arguments in the beginning of the program and return the file locations to the main program.

**ex.** `python test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -a <someotherfile> etc...`

Can this be done? I've found a way to do it, but the order has to precise and this will **not** do for my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `optparse` (before Python 2.7) or `argparse` (Python 2.7 or above).